# How to get rid of black edges in material image texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, image

[image]Good time to everyone! How to delete this unwanted black edges in materials of leaves, or what this edges black are? Thanks to all in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like the texture might have an alpha channel. Try connecting the Alpha output from your BaseColor image to the Alpha input of the Principled BSDF.

Comment: Ok, I will try.

Comment: But, how can I connect color and alpha at once? Thanks.

Comment: Connect the grey alpha dot from the image to the grey alpha dot on the BSDF (above the Normal input). Also connect the yellow dot from the image to the yellow dot of the BaseColor input of the BSDF.

Comment: Ok, I will try 2.0. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, thanks, it is finally solved.

Comment: Glad it works. So yeah, that's how you use Image alpha (transparency) in Cycles.